# ООП, Наследование

Tags: python, ооп

Есть 3 класса Stone, Seaweed и Place. Но при создании обьекта класса Seaweed пишет что нет атрибута X,Y. Как мне  использовать и новые атрибуты  **init** у seaweed, так наследуемые атрибуты place

```
class Place:
    color = (52,152,219)
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y 

    def aseta(self):
        square = pygame.Rect(self.x*10, self.y*10, 10, 10)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, square)

class Stone(Place):
    color = (0,0,0)

class Seaweed(Place):
    color = (2,124,2)
    def __init__(self, lifePeriod , age, reproductivePeriod ):
        self.lifePeriod = lifePeriod;
        self.age = age;
        self.reproductivePeriod = reproductivePeriod;

    def aging(self):
        self.age += 1 ;

    # def reproduction():

    # def dying():



pond = [[ 0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(width)]


for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        pond[x][y] = Place(x,y);
        pond[x][y].aseta()

pygame.display.flip();

num = 0

while num <= stone_count:
    x = random.randint(1,width-2)
    y = random.randint(1,height-2)
    if isinstance(pond[x][y], Place):
        pond[x][y] = Stone(x,y)
        pond[x][y].aseta();
        num += 1


pygame.display.flip();

seawedNum = 0
while seawedNum <= seawed_count:
    x = random.randint(1,width-2)
    y = random.randint(1,height-2)
    if isinstance(pond[x][y], Place):
        pond[x][y] = Seaweed(1,1,1)
        pond[x][y].aseta();
        seawedNum += 1

pygame.display.flip();
```

Comment: почитайте о методе `super`

Comment: У вас там и с созданием объектов `Place` проблема - вы ему на вход 3 аргумента передаёте, а он принимает 2.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да заметил, правил в спешке. Сейчас правлю

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В питоне в конструкторе подкласса, `Seaweed`, например, нужно вызывать конструктор предка. Ведь именно он добавляет в объект атрибуты.

Задача конструктор в принципе проинициализировать объект, так чтоб у него было правильное состояние, удовлетворяющее условиям целостности объекта. Атрибуты это частный случай. И вызов конструктора предка, это обязательно.